# headless false - focus always on address bar

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer with `headless=false` option, in order to let user type some details in a form, and then read the result, programmatically.
I want the cursor/focus will be on the first input field when the page loaded, but the focus is always on the address bar.
Is there a way to move the cursor/focus inside the page?

I already tried `await page.focus(selector)`.
Please find the below example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  let selector = ".w3-white.w3-padding.notranslate>form>input[name='firstname']";
  await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp');
  await page.waitForSelector(selector,{waitUntil :"networkidle2"});
  await page.focus(selector);
  await page.type(selector,"aaa");

  //await browser.close();
})();
```

I would like that after the page was loaded, the user will be able to type inside the input field, without having to "move" into the field first (by mouse or tab).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are setting the cursor inside the page, but the focus of the browser itself is still on the address bar.

To make the browser focus the page itself, you need to call [`page.bringToFront()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagebringtofront) which will set the focus of the browser to the tab. You should do it right after creating the page like this:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.bringToFront();
```

---

In addition, as already pointed out in the other answer, you are giving invalid options to the [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) function. This is simply ignored by puppeteer (and not related to your problem), but should be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This issue had me perplexed for years and I've finally found the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is one little thing that needs to be corrected, `waitUntil` is an option for `page.goto`:

```
await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp',{waitUntil :"networkidle2"});
```

With this in place your example works fine with puppeteer 1.11 and node 8.6

Answer (score 0):

I invoked mouse.click() function to move my cursor from address bar to the page.

```js
await page.mouse.click(0, 0);
```

The way to use browser.newPage() works as I expect, but that case uses more memory. So I uses click() function.